# Update Statement

Tags: c#, sql, textbox

How do I make it possible to update information in a database based on text that is input from another form?

What needs to happen (The forms used are in bold:

1. **StudiesForm** User logs in (types username and password in separate textboxes).
2. The information from the username textbox on the **StudiesForm** is saved and used as a reference in the select statement for displaying the details on the next form.
3. **UpdateMyDetailsForm** User sees their information and can update it.

Here is an attempt, however it calls the first row of data from the database and not the unique individuals.

```
private void UpdateMyDetailsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // Select Statement to automatically Load data to the form
        //VariableHandler vh = new VariableHandler();
        StudiesForm sf = new StudiesForm();
    sc.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from StudentRecords where ID ='" + sf.txtBoxUsername + "'", sc);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        comBoxFrm.Text = (myReader["Title"].ToString());
        txtBoxFName.Text = (myReader["First_Name"].ToString());
        txtBoxSName.Text = (myReader["Surname"].ToString());
        txtBoxHouseNum.Text = (myReader["House/Flat_Number"].ToString());
        txtBoxStreetName.Text = (myReader["Street_Name"].ToString());
        txtBoxTownCity.Text = (myReader["Town/City"].ToString());
        txtBoxCounty.Text = (myReader["County"].ToString());
        txtBoxPCode.Text = (myReader["Postal_Code"].ToString());
        txtBoxPhone.Text = (myReader["Telephone"].ToString());
        txtBoxEmail.Text = (myReader["Email"].ToString());

        sc.Close();

    }// end of select statement

}
```

Second attempt I tried to save the textbox value from the **StudiesForm** to a seperate class, then call the variable in the SQL command. Doing this caused the form to show all the details as blank.

I believe the issue is that because the **StudiesForm** hides after the user has logged in, the reference to the username text box disappears.

I tried to use `String.Copy(textbox)` to make a unique reference however that also didn't work.

Any ideas or suggestions? - This is also not a serious project so no worries about SQLi attacks or redundant code.

I guess what I'm asking is How Do I Reference A Textbox Value On A Different Form? In C#.

Thanks

Comment: Please use parameters instead of constructing your SQL string like that.

Comment: Please listen to ZippyV. Also, I see a couple `IDisposable` without `using`/`Dispose()`.

Comment: Do you mind referencing a link where I can read on such a topic. Sorry, this is just how I've be taught via tutorials.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx). It's a small change that makes a big difference.

Comment: As far as your question, if `sf.txtBoxUsername` is a reference to a `TextBox`, you should be using `sf.txtBoxUsername.Text`. Ideally `StudiesForm` should have the property `string UserName` rather than exposing its controls, though.

Comment: Yeah I've done that, however it doesn't work.